# gradle application plugin process finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: gradle

I've got class

```
public class MainClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Hello world!");
}

}
```

in the package `org.myapp`.
My `build.gradle` looks like this

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = "org.myapp.MainClass"
```

But when I run `gradle run` I've got an error

```
Execution failed for task ':run'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

What's the problem?
Full stacktrace

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved.

I moved my source files to `src/main/java`
After that - it compiles correct